# How to call checkbox function in angular-datatable?

Tags: angularjs, database, angular-datatables

I am trying to use http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/rowSelect
I am unable to call "toggleAll","toggleOne". I am not able to find out where I am doing wrong?

I tried with ng-change/ng-click both are not working?

can any one help me.

```
var vm=this;

     var initModel = function fnInitModel() {
              var titleHtml = '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="$ctrl.selectAll" ng-change="$ctrl.toggleAll($ctrl.selectAll, $ctrl.checkedSymbol)">';


                var data = vm.data;

                vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                    .withOption('data', data);

                vm.dtColumns = [
                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle(titleHtml).notSortable()
                        .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
                            vm.checkedSymbol = false;
                            return '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="$ctrl.checkedSymbol" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleOne($ctrl.checkedSymbol)">';
                        }),

                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('symbolName').withTitle('Symbol Name'),
                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastPrice').withTitle('Last Price'),


                ];



            };

        vm.$onInit = function fnInit() {
            initModel();
        };

        vm.$onChanges = function fnOnChanges() {
            initModel();
        };

      vm.toggleAll = function toggleAll (selectAll, selectedItems) {
        console.log("toggleAll Called")

        }
        vm.toggleOne = function toggleOne (selectedItems) {
            console.log("toggleOne Called")

        }
```

Comment: "*I tried with ng-change/ng-click both are not working*"? Because they are not recognised by Angular. Follow the example more narrow, you miss some rather important parts in the extract above.

Comment: I have same problem

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the next option.

```
.withOption('createdRow', function(row, data, dataIndex) {
        // Recompiling so we can bind Angular directive to the DT
        $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
    })
```

the documentation says it!